# Custom event for countdown javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-events

How do I create a custom event for when a timer is at zero. I call my custom element in another custom element and I want something to happen when the timer is at zero. I have a hard time understanding custom events, and I'm struggling with seeing how to use one in my case and where to put the event-listener.
This is my countdown element:

```
  class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
      super()
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
      this._div = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div')
    }

    timer (limit = 20) {
      let startingTime = limit
      const timer = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#timer')

      setInterval(updateInterval, 1000)

      function updateInterval () {
        if (startingTime >= 0) {
          const seconds = startingTime % 60
          timer.textContent = `00:${seconds}`
          startingTime--
        } else { timer.textContent = '00:0' }
      }
    }

    connectedCallback () {
      this.timer()
    }
  })
```

This is where I call the countdown element:

````
  customElements.define('quiz-questions',
  class extends HTMLElement {
   
    constructor () {
      super()
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
      this._div = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div')
      this._p = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('p')
      this._submit = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#submit')
      this.result = []
    }

   timer (limit = 20) {
      const timer = document.createElement('countdown-timer')
      this._div.appendChild(timer)
      timer.timer(limit)
    }
  
   connectedCallback () {
      this.timer()
    }
})
```
````

Comment: "*I call my custom element in another custom element*" - please post that code as well. It is where you should install the event listener. The timer class you posted only needs to create and dispatch the event.

Comment: I hope the change I made to the post is clear enough, otherwise let me know.

Comment: If you only need to run some code once the timer reaches 0, why not call that code inside the `else { timer.textContent = '00:0' }` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most idiomatic in this situation would be probably to use [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent):

```js
const timerElement = this;
function updateInterval () {
    if (startingTime >= 0) {
        const seconds = startingTime % 60
        timer.textContent = `00:${seconds}`
        startingTime--
    } else {
        timer.textContent = '00:00'
        // dispatch a custom event
        const timeIsUpEvent = new CustomEvent('time-is-up');
        timerElement.dispatchEvent(timeIsUpEvent);
    }
}
```

and then in some other component:

```js
this.addEventListener('time-is-up', (event) => {
    // do smth about it!
});
```

Also you might want to check out this article:

- [How to pass data between web components](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/13/how-to-pass-data-between-web-components/)

Answer (score 1):

Andrey his answer will not (always) work when Custom Element/Web Components are involved.
Because you explicitly need to set how Events bubble or "escape" shadowDOM

This **simplified** code shows 2 "start" "stop" buttons controlling a timer; multiple uses of Events

```js
document.addEventListener("countdown", (evt) => {
  console.log("Timer Changed", evt.detail);
});
document.addEventListener("start", (evt) => {
  console.log("start event never reaches document");
});

let eventOptions = { bubbles: true, composed: true };

customElements.define("count-down", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: "open"})
             .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      this.paused = false;
      this.addEventListener("start", (evt) => this.paused = false);
      this.addEventListener("pause", (evt) => this.paused = true);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.time = this.getAttribute("start") || 60;
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.innerHTML = this.paused ? this.time : this.time--;
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new CustomEvent("countdown", { ...eventOptions,
            detail: { id: this.id, time: this.time }
          })
        )}, 1000);
    }});
customElements.define("timer-buttons", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let countdown = this.getRootNode().host;
    this.innerHTML = ["start","pause"].map(name =>`<button>${name}</button>`).join``;
    this.onclick = (evt) => countdown.dispatchEvent(new Event(evt.target.innerText));
  }});
```

```html
<template id="COUNT-DOWN">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 2em;
    }
    span {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  Timer: <slot></slot><span></span>
  <timer-buttons></timer-buttons>
</template>

<count-down id=ONE></count-down>
<count-down id=TWO start=42></count-down>
<count-down id=THREE start=21></count-down>
```

#### Notes:

- 2 types of Events used
- the `CustomEvent` 'escapes' shadowDOM, so all 3 timers report their state to `document` in a `detail` *payload*
- The buttons Event (one for all buttons) is a default `new Event(buttonlabel)`; its **targeted** at the **host** element `countdown`
- So every `<count-down`> captures its own buttons, the events do not reach other elements
- You can add options for `new Event(buttonlabe , {...eventOptions})` as well, if you want Events to go up the DOM
- Instead of direct targetting `countdown` You could let buttons `{bubbles:true, composed:false}` so they reach listeners in its *shadowHost*, but don't escape shadowDOM
- You could do all this without shadowDOM, it is all about targetting (and/or bubbling) events **from** the correct DOM element.

Comment: Oh hello Danny and happy NY! 

Comment: Hey, Andrey, long time no see. I left the Microsoft world when they started using ReactJS for SharePoint; I am 100% into native Web Components. Have a good 21

Comment: Yep, I'm also not doing much MS anymore. Web components are cool ! Same you, have a wonderful 21st year of 21st century!!

Comment: https://iconmeister.github.io is one of my pet-projects; same as in SP days **small** is everything